# PostgreSQL SELECT JOIN query duplicate problem

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I use Postgresql.
I've got 2 tables. **messages** and **comments**. The messages table has *message*, *id*, *created_at* column. The comments table has *comment*, *main_message_id*, *id* column.

I store the data on this way:
**MESSAGES TABLE:**

- **message:** 'Test';
  **id:** 1;
  **created_at:** 2020.01.01;

**COMMENTS TABLE:**

- **comment:** 'First Comment for Test';
  **main_message_id:** 1;
  **id:** 1;
- **comment:** 'Second for Test';
  **main_message_id:** 1;
  **id:** 2;

I would like to create a query that give me back the result without duplicate the MESSAGE TABLE content.

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    messages.message, 
    messages.id, 
    messages.created_at, 
    comments.comment,
    comments.main_message_id,
    comments.id
FROM 
    messages 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL
    (
    SELECT
        comments.comment
    FROM 
        comments
    WHERE
        comments.main_message_id = message.id
    )
ON TRUE
ORDER BY 
    messages.created_at DESC
```

My result is looks like this:

```
+---------+-----+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----+
| message | id  | created_at |      comment        | main_message_id | id |
+---------+-----+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----+
| Test    |  1  | 2020.01.01 | Comment For Test 1  |               1 |  1 |
| Test    |  1  | 2020.01.01 | Comment For Test 2  |               1 |  2 |
+---------+-----+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----+
```

So Its duplicate the messages...

What i want is looks like this: (Without duplicate the messages table row.)

```
+---------+-----+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----+
| message | id  | created_at |      comment        | main_message_id | id |
+---------+-----+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----+
| Test    |  1  | 2020.01.01 | Comment For Test 1  |               1 |  1 |
|         |     |            | Comment For Test 2  |               1 |  2 |
+---------+-----+------------+---------------------+-----------------+----+
```

Comment: Please show us the expected results as *tabular text*. We cannot tell rows from columns in a bullet point list.

Comment: You need to aggregate data from `comments` table in some way to avoid duplication. For example: `select m.*, json_agg(c) from messages as m left outer join comments as c on (m.id = c.main_message_id) group by m.id order by m.created_at desc`

Comment: This kind of formatting is better done when you _display_ the data in your application. SQL isn't really suited for this. Btw: your lateral join is completely unnecessary and can be simplified to `LEFT JOIN comments on comments.main_message_id = message.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been commented already that this type of task is better performed on application side than in SQL, and I do agree with that.

That being said, one solution to your question is to uses `row_number()` to identify the "first" record per group, and a `case` expression do handle the conditional display:

```
SELECT 
    case when row_number() over(partition by m.id order by c.id) = 1 then m.message end message, 
    case when row_number() over(partition by m.id order by c.id) = 1 then m.id end id, 
    case when row_number() over(partition by m.id order by c.id) = 1 then m.created_at end created_at, 
    c.comment,
    c.main_message_id,
    c.id comment_id
FROM messages 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.main_message_id = m.id
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
```

Note: a `lateral join` adds unnecessary complexity - a simple `left join` is just good enough.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is much more simply written just using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT m.message, m.id, m.created_at, 
       c.comment, c.main_message_id, c.id
FROM messages m LEFT OUTER JOIN
     comments c
     ON c.main_message_id = m.id
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC;
```

Second, what you are discussing is *presentation*.  That is better done in  application code rather than in the database.  But it is possible.

One method uses `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.id ORDER BY c.id) = 1 THEN m.message END) as message,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.id ORDER BY c.id) = 1 THEN m.id END) as id,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.id ORDER BY c.id) = 1 THEN m.created_at END) as created_at,
       c.comment, c.main_message_id, c.id
FROM messages m LEFT OUTER JOIN
     comments c
     ON c.main_message_id = m.id
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC, m.id, c.id;
```

It is very important that the overall `ORDER BY` be consistent with the window function calls.  You want the *first* row in each group to have the columns from `message`.  Hence, the same `ORDER BY` keys used for the window frame need to be in the `ORDER BY`.